# Retorno de metodos assincronos javascript

Tags: javascript, return, assincronismo, promises

Gostaria de salvar o retorno de uma função assincrona. A função é a seguinte:

```
cb.tabela(serie).then(function(tabela) {
    console.log(tabela);
}, function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

o que eu queria era poder fazer algo como:

```
cb.tabela(serie).then(function(tabela) {
    return tabela;
}, function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

mas quando faço isso recebo um `Promise {<pending>}`. Existe alguma forma de salvar esse valor de retorno?

Comment: A idéia de trabalhar com métodos assícronos é justamente a de não existir trechos de código "parados", esperando a resolução de trechos mais lentos como chamadas externas (a API Fetch é um bom exemplo).
Nesse caso, em vez de retornar tabela, você deve chamar a função que precisa dela para continuar, como por exemplo "montaTabela(tabela);"...

Comment: Tens de "salvar esse retorno" no sitio onde tens `console.log(tabela);`. Há algum problema em colocar esse código aí?, ou uma chamada de função que passe `tabela);`?.  Podias usar async/await, mas se for coisa pouca assim pode ser mais simples.

Comment: nunk.lol eu tentei fazer isso, de chamar uma função pra manipular os dados mas nao consigo acessa-los, quando tento fazer isso recebo o Promise {<pending também>}

Answer (score 1):

Para obter o retorno da promise é necessário  que a mesma seja resolvida, conforme abaixo.
  Assim a regra só pode ser aplicada após o callback da função. Pois, como uma função assíncrona, ela não bloqueia o carregamento dos elementos da tela.
 No seu caso a regra para montar a tabela deve ser no retorno do callback ".then..".

```js
var tabela = '';
var contador = 0;

var p = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

       window.setTimeout(
        function() {
          // Cumprimos a promessa !
          resolve('Dados tabela');
        }, Math.random() * 8000 + 1000);
    });
}

p().then(function(result){
   //Adicionar regras
   console.log('Cumprimos a promessa');
   tabela = result;
  
});

setInterval(function(){
    contador++;
    if(contador > 10) return;
    console.log('Contador: ' + contador + ' - Tabela: ' + tabela);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: entao @Leandro, no caso minha função cb.tabela(serie) ja é a promise. Do jeito que voce fala em vez de eu fazer return new Promise como vc sugeriu, eu fiz return cb,tavela(serie), mas ainda assim nao obtive sucesso.

Comment: @roooooon na verdade new Promise utilizei somente para simular a sua situação, onde fiz p() é o mesmo que o seu cb.tabela(serie) o que sugeri é aplicar suas regras após o retorno  na função then